# If $A\times B$ is compact , then $A$ is compact and $B$ is compact?

Tags: general-topology

Is this true? I think so but I can't seem to prove it / know how to.

If $A\times B$ is compact then if $(x,y) \in A\times B$ then $x \in A$ and $y\in B$ and $(x,y)$ is covered by finite subsets of a D, this doesn't mean that $A$ is covered too?

Comment: Can you find continuous surjective maps $A\times B \to A$ and $A\times B \to B$?

Comment: Not necessarily. If $A=\mathbb R$ and $B$ is empty, then $A$ is not compact but $A\times B$ is compact.

Comment: Note that bof's example is somewhat pathological. If we insist that our spaces are non-empty, then the claim you state is true (see my post below)

Comment: just to add to Fischer's comment, finding such continuous surjective maps will show that A and B are compact because of the theorem which states that images of compact spaces under continuous maps are compact.

Answer (score 2):

I will assume you know the definition of a topological space and of a continuous map between topological spaces.

In order to answer your question, you need to understand the following concepts/theorems:

1. Concept: Compactness.
2. Concept: The product topology.
3. Theorem: If $f:X\to Y$ is a surjective continuous map between topological spaces and $X$ is compact, then $Y$ is compact.

I will guide you through the proof of the theorem:

We want to show that $Y$ is compact. So we start by taking an open cover $\{V_\gamma:\gamma \in \Gamma\}$ of $Y$. Now we want to use the fact that $X$ is compact, which involves being given an open cover for $X$ and reducing it to a finite subcover. How can we obtain this state of affairs?

We consider $\{U_\gamma=f^{-1}(V_\gamma):\gamma \in \Gamma\}.$ Since $f$ is continuous, each $U_\gamma$ is an open subset of $X$ (straight from the definition of continuity). Moreover, since the $V_\gamma$'s cover $Y$, the $U_\gamma$'s must cover $X$ (check this - it's just set theory). Now, as planned, we take a finite subcover, say $U_{\gamma_1},\ldots,U_{\gamma_1}$.

We finish off by moving back inside $Y$. Since $f$ is surjective, it follows that
$$V_{\gamma_1}=f(U_{\gamma_1}),\ldots,V_{\gamma_n}=f(U_{\gamma_n})$$
covers $Y$ (again, check this bit of set theory). So we have exhibited a finite subcover of a given open cover of $Y$ whence we have proved that $Y$ is compact. //

Can you now see how to use this theorem to establish your result?